# The portability issue of form definitions in Orbeon Forms

Tags: portability, orbeon

I store form definitions in an repository based on file systems. Each form definition in the repository has an `file-id`. In Orbeon Forms, a form definition is identified by `<app name, form name>` pair. So I use the `file-id` as `form name`. I wrote a customized persistence layer to bridge the Orbeon Forms and the repository according to [the persistence API](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api).

I want to copy/export/import form definitions from one repository to another, so as to share/reuse/migrate form definitions. When a form definition is copied from on repository to another, its `file-id` is changed, however, the `form name` in the form definition remains the old one. Just like copying a normal file to another directory or renaming it, but the file content is not changed.

In such a scenario, I will use `<app name, new file-id>` in persistence URL(API)  to access a form definition with `<app name, old file-id>` in its content. My first question is, which identify will take precedence, in form builder or form runner?

If the `<app name, new file-id>` in persistence URL(API) takes precedence in both form builder or form runner, the portability would be perfect. I tested in form builder, when saving or publishing, form builder will use the `<app name, old file-id>` in its content(XML). My second question is, can we change or customize the precedence?

Comment: I am not sure to understand how you save the data on disk in your persistence layer. What about the document id? With the bundled resource persistence layer, which reads data from disk (and is read-only), data is saved in a directory hierarchy that looks like the one here: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api#TOC-Virtual-hierarchy-of-data

Comment: Form definitions and form data are saved in separate place. Form data is saved in database. Form definitions are saved as files, each file has related meta data, `file-id` is one of such meta data.  I feel form data is not a problem; the key is form definitions.

Comment: See Erik's answer below, and also note that the app name / form name used by Form Builder comes from the form definition metadata, stored in the form definition document. So if you want to change the app name / form name, you should also change the form definition.

Comment: As avernet's suggestion, the `document` parameter works. When publishing forms, my persistence layer uses the `document` parameter instead of the `form name` in the metadata.

Comment: So, I imagine that a solution, if you want the app/form name to match the name of the file is to: 1. In your persistence layer, when saving/reading data, using the app/form name inside the XML document, instead of the document id. 2. When copying/renaming a form, also change the form/app name inside the XML document. Is this what you're thinking? (Or of course, you can give up on having the app/form name used for the file name, and use the document id, which would make everything simpler.)

Comment: In my solution, I don't use the `form name` inside the XML. I use this URL to call form builder:  
    `/orbeon/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/${fileId}`  
When publishing, form builder will call:  
   `/orbeon/fr/service/my-perisit/crud/${app-name-in-xml}/${form-name-in-xml}/form/form.xhtml?document=${fileId}`  
`my-persist` ignores `${form-name-in-xml}`

Comment: I see, and that is fine. But Form Builder won't be aware of that convention of yours; the app/form name Form Builder shows and changes will still come from the metadata stored inside the form's XML definition, not from the document id (in your case = fileId). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the API is documented [here](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api), and the properties and terminology [here](https://sites.google.com/a/orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner?pli=1#TOC-Persistence-layer-configuration).

To determine what persistence layer is used, Form Builder and Form Runner deal with only 3 parameters (we just made the terminology a bit more consistent):

- app name
- form name
- resource type (whether it's a form definition or form data)

The configuration properties (where you can use wildcards) determine, for each app/name/resource type combination, which persistence layer to use.

So the only place where some kind of precedence takes place is at the level of configuration properties for the persistence layer. Nothing else is relevant. For example, the default properties say:

```
<property
  as="xs:string"
  name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*"
  value="exist"/>
```

This means that, by default, everything goes through eXist.

But there is also:

```
<property as="xs:string"
  name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.orbeon.builder.form"
  value="resource"/>

<property
  as="xs:string"
  name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.orbeon.contact.form"
  value="exist"/>
```

This means, respectively, that the form definition for Form Builder itself is stored in the Orbeon Forms resources (generally in a JAR file). However, the form definition for the Contact form is stored in eXist. And so on with other properties.

When Form Builder stores form definitions with Save, it stores them as *form data* under the `orbeon/builder` app/form names. When it publishes forms, it stores them as *form definition* under its actual app/form name.

I hope this helps answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

@avernet, in my solution, I don't use the `form name` inside the XML. I use the following URL to call form builder:
    `/orbeon/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/${fileId}`
When publishing, form builder will call:
    `/orbeon/fr/service/my-perisit/crud/${app-name-in-xml}/${form-name-in-xml}/form/form.xhtml?document=${fileId}`
And my customized persistence layer `my-persist` ignores the `${form-name-in-xml}` parameter.

And I use `/orbeon/fr/${app name}/${fileId}/new` to call form runner.